# Returning all the data ignoring set year limit in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sqlbuilder

I have written the following query to return all the leaves that an employee has taken.

**What it should do**  is return values that lie in the current year and ignore the rest.

**What it is doing** is that it returns all the values in the table including values that pertain to previous years.

```
$sqlBuilder = new SQLQBuilder();

    $arrFields[0] = '`leave_date`';
    $arrFields[1] = '`leave_status`';

    $arrTable = "`leave_table`";

    $selectConditions[1] = "`employee_id` = '".$employeeId."'";
    $selectConditions[2] = "`leave_date` >= '".date('Y')."-01-01'";

    $query = $sqlBuilder->simpleSelect($arrTable, $arrFields, $selectConditions, $arrFields[0], 'ASC');

    $dbConnection = new DMLFunctions();

    $result = $dbConnection -> executeQuery($query);

    $leaveArr = $this->_buildObjArr($result);

    return $leaveArr;
```

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple

```
$selectConditions[2] = "year(`leave_date`) = year(now())";
```

Comment: Index may not be used if there is one on leave_date

Comment: This did not result in any change. I keep receiving leaves from previous year

Comment: what is type of your leave_date field

Comment: then it should be alright but i suggest you check your simpleSelect method if it is taking array in the third parameter and processing it alright.

Comment: crossed out this query and made a MySQL query using your method. Worked! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
where 
    leave_date>=current_date()-interval dayofyear(current_date())-1 day and
    leave_date<current_date()-interval dayofyear(current_date())-1 day+interval 1 year
```